# Adding new images to Fotorama slideshow

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, slider, fotorama

I'm looking for a good jQuery image slider with thumbnail previews to use for a web app I'm working on. I came across Fotorama.js and it seems to have most of the features I want, but I don't see anything in the documentation about adding more images via AJAX once the slider has been initialized. Does anyone have any experience with Fotorama? Is this supported? If not, can you recommend another light weight jQuery slider that has thumbnails and can work with AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Photorama and adding images manually via HTML. easy to install, many others didn't work for some reason. Figuring out how to add captions though....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add more images to the

```
<div id="my-fotorama">....</div>
```

via AJAX

You could initialize Photorama for this div by

`<script>
     $(function() {
    $('#my-fotorama').fotorama();
  });
</script>`